# How to make node fs async/await with classes?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, fs

I'm having a tricky time making a parser that can be asynchronous. I keep either getting a promise returned or gettings undefined returned. After reading some docs online, I'm pretty sure I need to institute a try/catch block, but I don't know where with the fs.readFile method. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
const fs = require('fs')
class CSV {
    constructor (fileName, buffer) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    async parseCSV () {
        let csv = this.fileName
        let buff = this.buffer
        let stream = await fs.readFile(csv, buff, (err, data) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            data = data.split('\r').toString().split('\n')
            this.returnData(data)
        })
        return stream
    }

    returnData(data) {
        return data
    }
}

let test = new CSV('./topsongs.csv', 'utf8')
let data = await test.parseCSV()
console.log(data)

module.exports = CSV
```

Answer (score 1):

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

`fs.readFile` doesn't return Promise, you need a Promise wrapper. You can either:

1. Promisify it manually with built-in `util.promisify`.

   ```
   const fs = require('fs');
   const promisify = require('util').promisify;
   const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

   let stream;
   try {
     stream = await fs.readFile(csv, buff); // callback omitted, `data` param returned instead
   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
   }
   ```
2. Drop-in a 3rd party native fs replacement library like [fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra).

   ```
   const fs = require('fs-extra');

   let stream;
   try {
     stream = await fs.readFile(csv, buff);
   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
   }
   ```